# Transaction results in syntax error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

This function is created ok without the transaction block. With it as in the following I get the following error...

> ERROR:  syntax error at end of input LINE 27:  $$
>             ^
>   ********** Error **********
>   ERROR: syntax error at end of input

If I take out the 'COMMIT' and corresponding 'BEGIN' then it runs ok.

Why is this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ContentDelete (
    creatorUserId BIGINT,
    toDeleteContentId BIGINT)

    RETURNS VOID

    AS $$
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            IF (SELECT EXISTS(SELECT
                        *
                    FROM
                        tbl_content
                    WHERE
                        ContentId = toDeleteContentId
                        AND
                        UserId = creatorUserId
                    LIMIT 1) AS "exists")

            THEN
                DELETE FROM tbl_content WHERE ParentContentId = toDeleteContentId;
                DELETE FROM tbl_content WHERE ContentId = toDeleteContentId;
            END IF;
        COMMIT;

    END
 $$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You can't use `commit` (or `rollback`) in a function in Postgres. The caller of the function needs to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions in PostgreSQL are running under transaction everywhere. It can be implicit transaction (started by Postgres) or explicit transaction (started by user). And you cannot to commit or rollback this transaction, because it is started outside function.

If your function doesn't raise a exception, then result will be committed (if somebody else doesn't raise a exception). If you would to enforce rollback - raise a exception. The only one solution is rollback of outer transaction. Your function can be strongly reduced in PostgreSQL (although your logic looks messy):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ContentDelete (creatorUserId BIGINT,
                                          toDeleteContentId BIGINT)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM tbl_content
     WHERE ContentId = toDeleteContentId
       AND UserId = creatorUserId;
  IF FOUND THEN
    DELETE FROM tbl_content WHERE ParentContentId = toDeleteContentId;
  END IF;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Interesting although your code would result in a referential integrity exception.

Comment: I don't know a context (complete schema), so it can be wrong - but usually we drop a content and later parent' nodes.

Comment: But your code drops the parent node first...? You can't drop a parent before the children because then the children would be referencing a row that doesn't exist.